# How to create a batch-file for URL link on computer desktop (windows)?

Tags: batch-file

How to create a batch-file for URL link on computer desktop (windows) reagardless what version of windows.

please share this file if you already have one

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

start iexplore.exe YourURL

start firefox.exe YourURL

I know this is not going to use the default browser, but then, I don't know what you want to do with it - and in which environment.

found it here:
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071107002712AAtMW19